# How to make occurrence matrix with pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

What I have is a four columns matrix. I want to keep the first two columns and turn last two columns into a sort of occurrence matrix(but with corresponding values). I tried to groupby ['shop_id', 'item_id', 'date'] but have no idea how to fill 0 for those empty date. Anyone have an idea? many thanks

```
given:
shop_id item_id date sales
0       19      0    1
0       19      2    13
0       19      3    11
1       19      1    3

result:
shop_id item_id date_0 date_1 date_2 date_3 
0       19      1      0      13     11
1       19      0      3      0      0
```

Comment: Thanks for all answers, I compared the set of solutions from Scott, piSquared and COLDSPEED with different data sizes(10**(i) for i in range(2,6)) in terms of time efficiency. It turns out the unstack() methods running with minimum time in the large dataset(larger than 1,000,000 rows) and defaultdict() is good at small dataset(samller than 10,000). The performance of pivot_table() is in the middle of those two methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use `set_index`, `unstack` and `fillna`:

```
df.set_index(['shop_id','item_id','date'])['sales'].unstack()\
  .add_prefix('date_').reset_index().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
date  shop_id  item_id  date_0  date_1  date_2  date_3
0           0       19       1       0      13      11
1           1       19       0       3       0       0
```

Comment: @HanZhang Would you [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) this answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that stack/unstack are pretty inefficient.

Comment: In my opinion: you should swap the order of `unstack()` and `['sales']` to `['sales'].unstack()`

Answer (score 2):

Using `defaultdict`

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
for (shop, item, date, sales) in df.values.tolist():
    d[date][(shop, item)] = sales

pd.DataFrame(d).fillna(0, downcast='infer') \
  .add_prefix('date_').rename_axis(['shop_id', 'item_id']).reset_index()

   shop_id  item_id  date_0  date_1  date_2  date_3
0        0       19       1       0      13      11
1        1       19       0       3       0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `pivot_table` solution, should be really fast -

```
df = df.pivot_table(
            index=['shop_id', 'item_id'], 
            columns=['date'],  
            values=['sales'], 
            fill_value=0)\
       .add_prefix('date_').reset_index()

df

     shop_id item_id date_sales                     
date                     date_0 date_1 date_2 date_3
0          0      19          1      0     13     11
1          1      19          0      3      0      0
```

Make sure you test out both solutions on your data before deciding which one to use!